# Symfony 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'symfony''

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm working on a symfony (2.5.*) project with some friend, and we're trying to get out website to work, but somehow it keeps crashing. We've tried updating to a newer version of symfony (2.*) and clearing caches, but nothing seems to work.

I believe the source of the problem is that somehow symfony tries to access a 'default' database instead of the database we have specified in the

```
    parameters.yml
```

Here is the file:

```
    parameters:
      database_driver: pdo_mysql
      database_host: 127.0.0.1
      database_port: 3306
      database_name: testdb
      database_user: root
      database_password: null
      mailer_transport: smtp
      mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
      mailer_user: null
      mailer_password: null
      secret: ThisIsVerySecret
      locale: en
      debug_toolbar: true
      debug_redirects: false
      use_assetic_controller: true
```

`Config.yml` -> doctrine part

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
      dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
      orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

The `paginaController` :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Cache;

class PaginaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function partnersAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
    /**
     * @Template
     * @Cache(expires="tomorrow")
     */
    public function homeAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function geschiedenisAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function profielAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function reunistenAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function linksAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

We have created an empty database called `symfony` to see what would happen. 
Ar first the page loads, but then we would receive the same error when trying to log in (because we still need to access data in the `testdb` database).

```
    Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'symfony.leden' doesn't exist
```

In this error, it also refers to the `symfony`-database, instead of the `testdb`-database.

Is there any possible way to fix this issue, and get symfony to recognize the right database (`testdb`) and not to access a non-excisting database called `symfony`?

Comment: Can you post what your config.yml contains for the `doctrine:` section?

Comment: I have added the part! Thanks for your help (in advance!).

Comment: Ok Pim, I see it. Thanks. Nothing wrong there. So when you use the debug URL (append `app_dev.php` to your URL) [See this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments) does it show you which controller it is using and which line? Can you post the relevant code from that controller that you get the EntityManager? Maybe you've specified Symfony there? Oh and make sure you have cleared your cache using `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've created the database called `symfony`, then you need to change this in your parameters.yml file:

```
database_name: symfony
```

Or from the command line you could run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

This would create the database in your parameters.yml file.

You also need to set the MySQL username and password. The default are 'root' and 'null', so that won't normally work.

---

EDIT #2
Sounds like a caching issue from the comments feedback. Try this from the command line:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

See if that works.

Comment: Hi Alvin, Thank you for your reply! I'm aware of how to create a new database, but I do NOT want to use the symfony-database, it was just an example of how i worked around the issue in the past. 
Do you know why symfony would refer to the symfony-database when I try to load the website, even when I specified in paramaters.yml that i wish to use 'testdb'?

Comment: I'll update my post once I see what you have in the `doctrine:` section of the config.yml file. I might also need to see you controller (only relevant code). This should be an "easy" fix, you probably just have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I've done this, now the page **does** render, (no errors thrown whatsoever). Very weird. without `app_dev.php` it crashes. Same goes for logging in. with `app_dev.php` I can login, without it crashes. I'll add the controller

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It **finally** works!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Remember to clear the cache when you make changes in your code.

Comment: I will from now on!